# Cfd Buy or Sell understanding

Tags: trading, cfd

i would like to understand the following picture [Example of trading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyQqn.png)

if i place this kind of position what dose mean The price is 20,00 ? when the Price of the cfd is 164,00 ?

Can you help me to understand this ?

Comment: My Italian isn't great but it looks like the limit price is 20 rather than either a bid or ask price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The price is 20,00 ?

It's not *telling* you the price is 20 - it's asking if you want to create a *limit order* at 20, meaning you only buy when the price drops *below* 20.

The price you'd actually pay *at that moment* is the ask price - which I'm assuming is the 164,91 (since the ask is always larger than the bid).  I do not speak Italian but Denaro and Lettera translate to "money" and "letter" so it may mean something else or it may be localized terms for "bid" and "ask".

Comment: ok but what dose is the margin of the 20% ?

Comment: @T-student it means you pay only 20% of the price upfront. When you sell you pay/receive the difference between the sales price and the original price, meaning you might get some or all of your margin back.